# Drop all rows of a dataframe based on another dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes, `df_1` and `df_2`. Both of them have `datetimeindex`, starting in `2022-01-01` and goes until `2022-08-14`. The first one, `df_1`, has hourly measurements, and the second one, `df_2`, has daily measurements.

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5424, 1),
                    columns=["Random"],
                    index=pd.date_range(start="20220101000000", end="20220814230000", freq='H'))
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 3, size=226),
                    columns=["Random"],
                    index=pd.date_range(start="20220101", end="20220814", freq='D'))
```

How could I drop all rows from `df_1` in which the same day of `df_2` has a measurement different from zero? For example, if the first two days of January have 6 and 7 as measurements, I would need to drop all 48 hours of those days in `df_1`.

Comment: @jezrael sorry for that, i have edited with some code to generate random data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) with filter rows by another DataFrame:

```
np.random.seed(123)
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5424, 1),
                    columns=["Random"],
                    index=pd.date_range(start="20220101000000", 
                                        end="20220814230000", freq='H'))
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 3, size=226),
                    columns=["Random"],
                    index=pd.date_range(start="20220101", end="20220814", freq='D'))



df = pd.merge_asof(df_1, df_2, left_index=True, right_index=True)
df = df[df['Random_y'].ne(0)]
print (df)
                     Random_x  Random_y
2022-01-01 00:00:00  0.696469         1
2022-01-01 01:00:00  0.286139         1
2022-01-01 02:00:00  0.226851         1
2022-01-01 03:00:00  0.551315         1
2022-01-01 04:00:00  0.719469         1
                      ...       ...
2022-08-14 19:00:00  0.461419         2
2022-08-14 20:00:00  0.181182         2
2022-08-14 21:00:00  0.676527         2
2022-08-14 22:00:00  0.213839         2
2022-08-14 23:00:00  0.049919         2

[3696 rows x 2 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

To add:
How to **drop** all rows from `df_1` in which the same day of `df_2` has a measurement different from zero `(df_2.values != 0)`?

```
df = pd.merge_asof(df_1, df_2, left_index=True, right_index=True, suffixes=('_hr','_dy'))
f = (df.Random_dy.ne(0))
df[~f]
print(df)
                        Random_hr   Random_dy
2022-01-04 00:00:00     0.627249            0
2022-01-04 01:00:00     0.723416            0
2022-01-04 02:00:00     0.016129            0
2022-01-04 03:00:00     0.594432            0
2022-01-04 04:00:00     0.556785            0
...     ...     ...          ...
2022-08-13 19:00:00     0.421366            0
2022-08-13 20:00:00     0.465843            0
2022-08-13 21:00:00     0.660536            0
2022-08-13 22:00:00     0.778594            0
2022-08-13 23:00:00     0.629758            0

1728 rows × 2 columns
```